# Conditional builds in VSTS

Tags: build, azure-devops, conditional-statements, devops

How to trigger conditional builds in Azure DevOps(VSTS) based on changes in a particular folder(This is in reference to yarn work spaces).I have tried it for particular branch.

Comment: How is your problem progressing? Is the following answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify file paths to include in the paths of yaml.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - README.md
```

When you specify paths, you also need to explicitly specify branches to trigger on.

You can also set Path filters in the Triggers of the Build pipeline.
[image]

For details , please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) .